# What is the Equation M use to devour the Metacreatures?

Tags: shikkoku-no-sharnoth

In Shikkoku no Sharnoth -What a Beautiful Tomorrow-, when M goes to "devour" a Metacreature, Mary describes that what is M is using is an equation with some of the patterns being Monumental Kadathian.

In Sekien no Inganock -What a Beautiful People- which takes place before Shikkoku no Sharnoth, Gii and Kerkan both use the Phenomenon Equation, Gii uses a healing one while Kerkan uses a destruction one however Gii mentions that there are many other Equations that one could use.

So what is the Equation M is using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called the **Kruschtya Equation** which unlike the Phenomenon Equation, was developed by himself. It is used to bind his original form so he has the appearance of a human, When he "unties" the Equation, his body begins to shape shift back to it's original form

[image: Kruschtya Equation being untied]

The above image is the most commonly seen form as his final form only appears for a breif moment, there is a hybrid from where just he's head is shown, this is shown in 2 places

- In the Shikkoku no Sharnoth Visual Novel when he encounters Bram Stoker at around the same time Troll has been consumed (this may however be his other side who poses as Baron Münchausen as the CG of M laughing shows he has a human face at this moment)
- In the Shikkoku no Sharnoth Web Novel where he removes the water spray the fake Metacreature splash on Mary's neck, he does this by changing his head head to it's original form and merging his shadows into Mary's neck to remove the spray that was infecting her body (Sebas mentions just before that it has "permeated below the skin, and is eroding her bodily functions"), however because of the spray's effect on her body Mary does not notice any Equation use